# Why is the list returning just the first element in my Flask API reqParse arguments?

Tags: python, api, flask, post, flask-restful

I just begun learning Flask API and Flask_Restful API. I have an error.

In my main.py file I am getting the user information from the arguments they sent, in the post request.

```
user_post_args = reqparse.RequestParser()
user_post_args.add_argument("username", type=str, help="Username is required", required=True)
user_post_args.add_argument("password", type=str, help="Password is required", required=True)
user_post_args.add_argument("first name", type=str, help="First Name is required", required=True)
user_post_args.add_argument("last name", type=str, help="Last Name is required", required=True)
user_post_args.add_argument("pictures", type=list, help="Pictures are required", required=True)
```

My test.py file has

```
response = requests.post(BASE + "userInformation/", 
        {
        "username": "Tamir", 
        "password": "1234567890", 
        "first name": "Tamir",
        "last name": "Polyakov",
        "pictures": [4,3,2,1,0],
}
```

My post function looks like this

```
    def post(self):
        args = user_post_args.parse_args()
        print(args)
```

However it just prints the first element, 4, in pictures.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use argument *action*:

```
user_post_args.add_argument("pictures", type=int, action="append", help="Pictures are required", required=True)
```